# How to embed ipython notebook to webpage?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have developed predictive model in jupyter notebook(Python 3.0) which takes input ( 5 features) and predicts the outcome out of it. I want to visualize the output on the webpage using JavaScript. 
After going through lot of feeds, I found Django or flask could be useful but I don't know how to use it with notebook.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Novice programmer here, apologies for the language. Thank you

Comment: Do you want to export a static version of the notebook with the results or a "live" notebook that you can actually interact with? For the first one, see [`nbconvert`](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io). For the second one, just need to expose the IPython/Jupyter server to the outside.

Comment: I looked into nbconvert but I don't think I need static version. I want to export interactive notebook. Could you tell me how do I do the latter one? Thanks!

Comment: hey, did you find any solution for this?